# How to center text box and left align its attached label

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have an ASPX page that looks like the following:

```
<div style="text-align:left">
    <asp:Label id="uLbl" runat="server">Username:</asp:Label><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="uTxt"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label id="upLbl" runat="server">Password:</asp:Label> <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="uPw" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

I want to center-align the `TextBox` within the `div` element that it's in, but I want to align the left side of the text to match with the left side of the text box.

I know I could use `padding` css style to do it, but depending on the size of the screen, etc., it would probably end up varying the actual size of the control (or maybe that is the right solution, and I'm just too dumb to figure it out).

Comment: just to clarify, you want the Labels at the left edge, but the TextBox in the middle? Is that right?

Comment: I want the labels aligned with the left edge of the text box that's in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** accoring to comment:

```html
    <div style="text-align: left; display: table; margin: auto;">
        <asp:Label ID="uLbl" runat="server">Username:</asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="uTxt"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="upLbl" runat="server">Password:</asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="uPw" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

It sets the `display` to `'table'`, and sets `margin` to `'auto'`. Setting `margin` to `auto` will center the div in it's parent. Setting `display` to 'table' is a trick, so you can center elements without specifying a Width.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I currently have, but that means that my text box isn't perfectly centered (and I'm a bit of a perfectionist).